# Is it possible to invest or participate in cryptocurrencies (e.g. Bitcoin) in a halal way?

Tags: halal-haram, money, technology

Someone I know proposed to me a kind of a "job". It is something based on [cryptocurrencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency), and there is an earning plan, binary system, and commission, where we produce coins by renting a server which digs/mines coins for us.  There are different levels of investing, explained in this YouTube presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xl-Oq_aGE4.

A lot of people I know are investing in this, and they earn money. So if it's legal, I would like to not miss a chance to earn money and if it is a large amount, help family, friends, people in need with this money.

[CoinSpace](http://coinspace.com/) is the first network marketing company that provides cloud service mining investors, networkers and giving beginners the opportunity to be part of the rapidly growing industry of the crypto-mint.

As you see, it's lot of promises, and there are already evidence that it works.  But I don't want to partake in this, if it's not legal in the eyes of God. I prefer being poor on Earth if the Creator does not bless in my work.

If there is some haram points, can you tell me if it is halal to:

- Invest with two friends; initially investing a big amount, and don't need to "take" the money of others to make bigger turnover. E.g., we jointly invest 36,000 Euros, and we will be able to profit of the 1,000 Euro/day earning plan, so it is 30,000 Euro/month so we can divide this into 3 equal parts.
- It is ok to only rent a digging server, and just sell the produced coins to the company?  Or save them until the introduction of the crypto money to the stock market? And not to invest on the others things like binary, and commissions stuff?